arXiv compiler error: Not loaded/selectlanguage/Emergency stop
I'm uploading a document to arXiv, but I have this rather cryptic error from the arXiv LaTeX compiler.
! Not loaded.
\selectlanguage ...ing it}\errmessage {Not loaded}

l.102 ...ad to divergences in {2D} diffusion}},\ }
\href {https://doi.org/10....

?
! Emergency stop.
\selectlanguage ...ing it}\errmessage {Not loaded}

l.102 ...ad to divergences in {2D} diffusion}},\ }
\href {https://doi.org/10....

! ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
Transcript written on main.log.

[verbose]: pdflatex 'main.tex' failed.

How can I debug this error? \selectlanguage is not in my source, but I'm struggling to understand from this message if that is the real source of the error.

What a cryptic error! Although typing h (for help) an explanation is shown, it should be more explanatory. I'll take note to modify it.

@JavierBezos great, thanks. However the truncation of the error message (I guess this is arXiv's doing) seems to be the real problem - if the whole message \selectlanguage{\errhelp{Selecting a language requires a package supporting it} was shown instead of just \selectlanguage ...ing it} maybe I would have got there

The error you show is from babel:
  \def\selectlanguage{%
    \errhelp{Selecting a language requires a package supporting it}%
    \errmessage{Not loaded}}%

and means you have selected a language that is not set up eg
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\selectlanguage{french} oops

\end{document}


produces
! Not loaded.
\selectlanguage ...ing it}\errmessage {Not loaded}
                                                  
l.5 \selectlanguage
                   {french} oops
? 

and the fix is to add (for example) \usepackage[french]{babel} this runs without error
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\begin{document}

\selectlanguage{french} oops

\end{document}


actually even just \usepackage{babel} is enough to avoid this error (as long as french hyphenations are installed in the format) You don't need an explicit french option 9although that's probably a good idea for other reasons if you have French text.
